# How to extract mutiple xml tags in elementtree in Python?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

My `xml` data looks like below. I am trying to extract `"weighted_avg"` and `"change_in_wtd_avg"` for `"CUTTER/CANNER"` and `"FROZEN CUTTER/CANNER"`. For this I have below code, where I can print only data from either `"CUTTER/CANNER"` or `"FROZEN CUTTER/CANNER"`. I am not sure how can I get the data from `"CUTTER/CANNER"` and `"FROZEN CUTTER/CANNER"` in the same output. I am new to `xml` and `python` `ElementTree`.

**XML Data**

```
b'<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?><results exportTime="2021-01-03 13:16:25 CDT"><report label="National" slug="LM_XB001"><record report_date="01/24/2009" narrative="null"><report label="Current Cutout Value/Change"><record current_cutout_value="232.67" change_cutout_value="-.03"/></report><report label="Items"><record item_desc="90% lean  " current_price="276.93" current_value="154.64" change_value=".00"/><record item_desc="100% lean inside round  " current_price="563.93" current_value="13.08" change_value=".09"/><record item_desc="100% lean, flats and eyes  " current_price="429.52" current_value="9.96" change_value=".00"/><record item_desc="100% lean, S.P.B.  " current_price="431.54" current_value="21.58" change_value=".00"/><record item_desc="Chuck Tender  " current_price="311.27" current_value="3.11" change_value="-.02"/><record item_desc="Knuckle  4-7 lbs." current_price="323.60" current_value="8.19" change_value=".01"/><record item_desc="Tenderloin  2-3 lbs." current_price="442.55" current_value="2.35" change_value="-.06"/><record item_desc="Tenderloin  3-4 lbs." current_price="663.86" current_value="4.91" change_value=".00"/><record item_desc="Ribeye Roll  4-6 lbs." current_price="405.00" current_value="4.25" change_value=".00"/><record item_desc="Ribeye Roll  6-8 lbs." current_price="392.05" current_value="2.90" change_value="-.06"/><record item_desc="Ribeye Roll  8up lbs." current_price="435.00" current_value="3.18" change_value=".00"/><record item_desc="Flank Steak  " current_price="367.34" current_value="1.54" change_value=".01"/><record item_desc="Kidney, Edible  " current_price="40.00" current_value=".18" change_value=".00"/><record item_desc="Fat, inedible  " current_price="44.72" current_value="1.04" change_value=".00"/><record item_desc="Bone  " current_price="7.32" current_value="1.76" change_value=".00"/></report><report label="Current Volume"><record boner_volume_loads="17.31" cutter_volume_loads="4.11" bbcc_volume_loads="19.47" lean_volume_loads="19.09" frozen_volume_loads="4.61" boner_volume_pounds="692,580" cutter_volume_pounds="164,565" bbcc_volume_pounds="778,700" lean_volume_pounds="763,409" frozen_volume_pounds="184,527"/></report><report label="BONER/BREAKER"><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll, 6-8 lbs. (112)" number_trades="11" total_pounds="67,507" weighted_avg="496.91" change_in_wtd_avg="4.35"/><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll, 8-10 lbs. (112)" number_trades="32" total_pounds="45,014" weighted_avg="563.10" change_in_wtd_avg="-8.29"/><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll, 10-up lbs. (112)" number_trades="52" total_pounds="110,549" weighted_avg="523.10" change_in_wtd_avg="-6.89"/><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll-lip-on, 8-dn lbs. (112A)" number_trades="9" total_pounds="14,619" weighted_avg="745.28" change_in_wtd_avg=".72"/><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll-lip-on, 8-up lbs. (112A)" number_trades="18" total_pounds="23,518" weighted_avg="590.82" change_in_wtd_avg="-8.21"/><record item_desc="Chuck, boneless 85% ( )" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Chuck, brisket (120)" number_trades="13" total_pounds="21,366" weighted_avg="320.60" change_in_wtd_avg="-.72"/><record item_desc="Round, top inside, 10-dn lbs. (168)" number_trades="13" total_pounds="43,841" weighted_avg="288.11" change_in_wtd_avg="-3.57"/><record item_desc="Round, top inside, 10-up lbs. (168)" number_trades="5" total_pounds="4,188" weighted_avg="378.20" change_in_wtd_avg=".00"/><record item_desc="Round, top inside c-off, 8-10 lbs. (169A)" number_trades="null" total_pounds="null" weighted_avg="null" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Round, top inside c-off, 10-14 lbs. (169A)" number_trades="14" total_pounds="160,462" weighted_avg="426.16" change_in_wtd_avg=".00"/><record item_desc="Round, top inside c-off, 14-up lbs. (169A)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Round, outside round (171B)" number_trades="6" total_pounds="22,900" weighted_avg="432.18" change_in_wtd_avg=".00"/><record item_desc="Round, eye of round (171C)" number_trades="37" total_pounds="69,061" weighted_avg="418.83" change_in_wtd_avg="1.02"/><record item_desc="Loin, Semi-Bnls Short Loin, 13-dn lbs. ( )" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Loin, Semi-Bnls Short Loin, 13-up lbs. ( )" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Loin, strip, bnls, 7-9 lbs. (180)" number_trades="5" total_pounds="3,232" weighted_avg="337.92" change_in_wtd_avg=".53"/><record item_desc="Loin, strip, bnls, 9-up lbs. (180)" number_trades="28" total_pounds="36,542" weighted_avg="364.57" change_in_wtd_avg="-8.85"/><record item_desc="Loin, sirloin butt (182)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Loin, top sirloin butt (184)" number_trades="17" total_pounds="29,315" weighted_avg="316.51" change_in_wtd_avg=".57"/><record item_desc="Loin, bottom sirloin butt flap, bnls. (185A)" number_trades="13" total_pounds="36,343" weighted_avg="376.82" change_in_wtd_avg="9.17"/><record item_desc="Loin, butt tender, peeled (191A)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/></report><report label="CUTTER/CANNER"><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll, 4-6 lbs. (112)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll, 6-8 lbs. (112)" number_trades="42" total_pounds="164,565" weighted_avg="389.13" change_in_wtd_avg="-11.84"/><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll, 8-up lbs. (112)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/></report><report label="100% LEAN"><record item_desc="Inside round - Combo" number_trades="16" total_pounds="101,110" weighted_avg="561.59" change_in_wtd_avg="1.95"/><record item_desc="Inside round - Boxed" number_trades="27" total_pounds="40,350" weighted_avg="569.80" change_in_wtd_avg="8.22"/><record item_desc="Outside round" number_trades="4" total_pounds="33,558" weighted_avg="429.74" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Eye of round" number_trades="19" total_pounds="30,408" weighted_avg="435.41" change_in_wtd_avg="-.74"/><record item_desc="Flats and eyes - Combo" number_trades="14" total_pounds="206,885" weighted_avg="428.61" change_in_wtd_avg="-.30"/><record item_desc="Flats and eyes - Boxed" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Striploin" number_trades="81" total_pounds="243,034" weighted_avg="466.56" change_in_wtd_avg="-1.73"/><record item_desc="S.P.B. - Combo" number_trades="12" total_pounds="108,064" weighted_avg="431.54" change_in_wtd_avg="-.06"/><record item_desc="S.P.B. - Boxed" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/></report><report label="B/B and C/C"><record item_desc="Chuck, chuck tender (116B)" number_trades="30" total_pounds="73,521" weighted_avg="311.27" change_in_wtd_avg="-2.08"/><record item_desc="Round, knuckle, peeled (167A)" number_trades="39" total_pounds="199,293" weighted_avg="323.60" change_in_wtd_avg=".28"/><record item_desc="Loin, tenderloin, 2-3 lbs. (190)" number_trades="6" total_pounds="8,983" weighted_avg="447.16" change_in_wtd_avg="-12.52"/><record item_desc="Loin, tenderloin, 3-4 lbs. (190)" number_trades="43" total_pounds="69,979" weighted_avg="663.86" change_in_wtd_avg=".20"/><record item_desc="Loin, tenderloin, 4-5 lbs. (190)" number_trades="169" total_pounds="212,729" weighted_avg="773.68" change_in_wtd_avg="-4.71"/><record item_desc="Loin, tenderloin, 5-up lbs. (190)" number_trades="37" total_pounds="43,056" weighted_avg="617.55" change_in_wtd_avg="13.85"/><record item_desc="Flank, flank steak (193)" number_trades="82" total_pounds="116,533" weighted_avg="390.93" change_in_wtd_avg="1.18"/><record item_desc="Flank, rough ()" number_trades="44" total_pounds="54,606" weighted_avg="322.56" change_in_wtd_avg="-5.70"/></report><report label="FROZEN BONER/BREAKER"><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll, 6-8 lbs. (112)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll, 8-10 lbs. (112)" number_trades="6" total_pounds="16,005" weighted_avg="473.41" change_in_wtd_avg=".00"/><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll, 10-up lbs. (112)" number_trades="null" total_pounds="null" weighted_avg="null" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll-lip-on, 8-dn lbs. (112A)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll-lip-on, 8-up lbs. (112A)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Round, top inside c-off, 8-10 lbs. (169A)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Round, top inside c-off, 10-14 lbs. (169A)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Round, top inside c-off, 14-up lbs. (169A)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Loin, strip, bnls, 7-9 lbs. (180)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Loin, strip, bnls, 9-up lbs. (180)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/></report><report label="FROZEN CUTTER/CANNER"><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll, 4-6 lbs. (112)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll, 6-8 lbs. (112)" number_trades="5" total_pounds="85,800" weighted_avg="397.65" change_in_wtd_avg="-2.26"/><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll, 8-up lbs. (112)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/></report><report label="FROZEN B/B and C/C"><record item_desc="Loin, tenderloin, 2-3 lbs. (190)" number_trades="null" total_pounds="null" weighted_avg="null" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Loin, tenderloin, 3-4 lbs. (190)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Loin, tenderloin, 4-5 lbs. (190)" number_trades="null" total_pounds="null" weighted_avg="null" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Loin, tenderloin, 5-up lbs. (190)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Flank, flank steak (193)" number_trades="10" total_pounds="77,922" weighted_avg="332.06" change_in_wtd_avg="-.32"/></report></record></report></results>'
```

**Code:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

r1 = requests.get(xml link)
root1 = ET.fromstring(r1.content)

    for child in root1.find(".//report[@label='CUTTER/CANNER']"):
        print(child.attrib.get('weighted_avg'),child.attrib.get('change_in_wtd_avg'))
```

**Expected Output:**

```
null     null
399.75   .65
457.78    .00
.00      null
413.49   3.73
.00      null
```

Comment: you could create minimal working code so we could run it. Maybe you need `.//report[@label='BONER/BREAKER' or @label='100% LEAN']`

Comment: what if you run your code only for `"100% LEAN"` and next only for `"BONER/BREAKER"` - you will have all results on the same output. Probably if you use `xpath` wiith `or` then you get exactly the same output.

Comment: I tried your suggested code.However, I am getting an error that says "SyntaxError: invalid predicate". Any idea ? The reason for not running the code separately is I feel like it will be repetattive. Can you please elaborate more on xpath ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a representative sample of your expected output?

Comment: Thank you! I updated the expected output

Comment: The numbers you want in your expected output are not in the `XML DATA` in your question.

Comment: it works for me if I uses `xpath()` instead of `find()`. I think it will not repeate if you will run first only for `"100% LEAN"` and next only for `"BONER/BREAKER"`

Comment: in original question you have `"100% LEAN"` and `"BONER/BREAKER"` and it will not repeate values but for `"CUTTER/CANNER"` and `"FROZEN CUTTER/CANNER"` it should get all values for both if you use only `@label="CUTTER/CANNER"` or you can try `contains(@label, "CUTTER/CANNER")`

Comment: sorry, I tested it with module `lxml` which has function `xpath()` and it can use `or` and `contains()` but it seems `xml` doesn't have `xpath()` and function `find()` can't use `or` and `contains()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should run `for`-loop two times

```py
for child in root1.find(".//report[@label='CUTTER/CANNER']"):
    print(child.attrib.get('weighted_avg'), child.attrib.get('change_in_wtd_avg'))    

for child in root1.find(".//report[@label='FROZEN CUTTER/CANNER']"):
    print(child.attrib.get('weighted_avg'), child.attrib.get('change_in_wtd_avg'))
```

and it shouldn't repeate values.

But I would use `findall()` instead of `find()` to get all elements if there is more `'CUTTER/CANNER'` and more `'FROZEN CUTTER/CANNER'`

```py
for item in root1.findall(".//report[@label='CUTTER/CANNER']"):
    for child in item:
        print(child.attrib.get('weighted_avg'), child.attrib.get('change_in_wtd_avg'))

for item in root1.findall(".//report[@label='FROZEN CUTTER/CANNER']"):
    for child in item:
        print(child.attrib.get('weighted_avg'), child.attrib.get('change_in_wtd_avg'))
```

---

Using module [lxml](https://lxml.de) you could use function `xpath()` instead of `find()` and it can use `or` or `contains()`

(doc for `xml` shows [XPath support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support) and it doesn't support all XPath functions)

```py
for item in root1.xpath(".//report[@label='CUTTER/CANNER' or @label='FROZEN CUTTER/CANNER']"):
    for child in item:
        print(child.attrib.get('weighted_avg'), child.attrib.get('change_in_wtd_avg'))
```

```py
for item in root1.xpath(".//report[contains(@label, 'CUTTER/CANNER')]"):
    for child in item:
        print(child.attrib.get('weighted_avg'), child.attrib.get('change_in_wtd_avg'))
```

---

Minimal working example

```py
content = b'<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?><results exportTime="2021-01-03 13:16:25 CDT"><report label="National" slug="LM_XB001"><record report_date="01/24/2009" narrative="null"><report label="Current Cutout Value/Change"><record current_cutout_value="232.67" change_cutout_value="-.03"/></report><report label="Items"><record item_desc="90% lean  " current_price="276.93" current_value="154.64" change_value=".00"/><record item_desc="100% lean inside round  " current_price="563.93" current_value="13.08" change_value=".09"/><record item_desc="100% lean, flats and eyes  " current_price="429.52" current_value="9.96" change_value=".00"/><record item_desc="100% lean, S.P.B.  " current_price="431.54" current_value="21.58" change_value=".00"/><record item_desc="Chuck Tender  " current_price="311.27" current_value="3.11" change_value="-.02"/><record item_desc="Knuckle  4-7 lbs." current_price="323.60" current_value="8.19" change_value=".01"/><record item_desc="Tenderloin  2-3 lbs." current_price="442.55" current_value="2.35" change_value="-.06"/><record item_desc="Tenderloin  3-4 lbs." current_price="663.86" current_value="4.91" change_value=".00"/><record item_desc="Ribeye Roll  4-6 lbs." current_price="405.00" current_value="4.25" change_value=".00"/><record item_desc="Ribeye Roll  6-8 lbs." current_price="392.05" current_value="2.90" change_value="-.06"/><record item_desc="Ribeye Roll  8up lbs." current_price="435.00" current_value="3.18" change_value=".00"/><record item_desc="Flank Steak  " current_price="367.34" current_value="1.54" change_value=".01"/><record item_desc="Kidney, Edible  " current_price="40.00" current_value=".18" change_value=".00"/><record item_desc="Fat, inedible  " current_price="44.72" current_value="1.04" change_value=".00"/><record item_desc="Bone  " current_price="7.32" current_value="1.76" change_value=".00"/></report><report label="Current Volume"><record boner_volume_loads="17.31" cutter_volume_loads="4.11" bbcc_volume_loads="19.47" lean_volume_loads="19.09" frozen_volume_loads="4.61" boner_volume_pounds="692,580" cutter_volume_pounds="164,565" bbcc_volume_pounds="778,700" lean_volume_pounds="763,409" frozen_volume_pounds="184,527"/></report><report label="BONER/BREAKER"><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll, 6-8 lbs. (112)" number_trades="11" total_pounds="67,507" weighted_avg="496.91" change_in_wtd_avg="4.35"/><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll, 8-10 lbs. (112)" number_trades="32" total_pounds="45,014" weighted_avg="563.10" change_in_wtd_avg="-8.29"/><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll, 10-up lbs. (112)" number_trades="52" total_pounds="110,549" weighted_avg="523.10" change_in_wtd_avg="-6.89"/><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll-lip-on, 8-dn lbs. (112A)" number_trades="9" total_pounds="14,619" weighted_avg="745.28" change_in_wtd_avg=".72"/><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll-lip-on, 8-up lbs. (112A)" number_trades="18" total_pounds="23,518" weighted_avg="590.82" change_in_wtd_avg="-8.21"/><record item_desc="Chuck, boneless 85% ( )" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Chuck, brisket (120)" number_trades="13" total_pounds="21,366" weighted_avg="320.60" change_in_wtd_avg="-.72"/><record item_desc="Round, top inside, 10-dn lbs. (168)" number_trades="13" total_pounds="43,841" weighted_avg="288.11" change_in_wtd_avg="-3.57"/><record item_desc="Round, top inside, 10-up lbs. (168)" number_trades="5" total_pounds="4,188" weighted_avg="378.20" change_in_wtd_avg=".00"/><record item_desc="Round, top inside c-off, 8-10 lbs. (169A)" number_trades="null" total_pounds="null" weighted_avg="null" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Round, top inside c-off, 10-14 lbs. (169A)" number_trades="14" total_pounds="160,462" weighted_avg="426.16" change_in_wtd_avg=".00"/><record item_desc="Round, top inside c-off, 14-up lbs. (169A)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Round, outside round (171B)" number_trades="6" total_pounds="22,900" weighted_avg="432.18" change_in_wtd_avg=".00"/><record item_desc="Round, eye of round (171C)" number_trades="37" total_pounds="69,061" weighted_avg="418.83" change_in_wtd_avg="1.02"/><record item_desc="Loin, Semi-Bnls Short Loin, 13-dn lbs. ( )" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Loin, Semi-Bnls Short Loin, 13-up lbs. ( )" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Loin, strip, bnls, 7-9 lbs. (180)" number_trades="5" total_pounds="3,232" weighted_avg="337.92" change_in_wtd_avg=".53"/><record item_desc="Loin, strip, bnls, 9-up lbs. (180)" number_trades="28" total_pounds="36,542" weighted_avg="364.57" change_in_wtd_avg="-8.85"/><record item_desc="Loin, sirloin butt (182)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Loin, top sirloin butt (184)" number_trades="17" total_pounds="29,315" weighted_avg="316.51" change_in_wtd_avg=".57"/><record item_desc="Loin, bottom sirloin butt flap, bnls. (185A)" number_trades="13" total_pounds="36,343" weighted_avg="376.82" change_in_wtd_avg="9.17"/><record item_desc="Loin, butt tender, peeled (191A)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/></report><report label="CUTTER/CANNER"><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll, 4-6 lbs. (112)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll, 6-8 lbs. (112)" number_trades="42" total_pounds="164,565" weighted_avg="389.13" change_in_wtd_avg="-11.84"/><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll, 8-up lbs. (112)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/></report><report label="100% LEAN"><record item_desc="Inside round - Combo" number_trades="16" total_pounds="101,110" weighted_avg="561.59" change_in_wtd_avg="1.95"/><record item_desc="Inside round - Boxed" number_trades="27" total_pounds="40,350" weighted_avg="569.80" change_in_wtd_avg="8.22"/><record item_desc="Outside round" number_trades="4" total_pounds="33,558" weighted_avg="429.74" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Eye of round" number_trades="19" total_pounds="30,408" weighted_avg="435.41" change_in_wtd_avg="-.74"/><record item_desc="Flats and eyes - Combo" number_trades="14" total_pounds="206,885" weighted_avg="428.61" change_in_wtd_avg="-.30"/><record item_desc="Flats and eyes - Boxed" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Striploin" number_trades="81" total_pounds="243,034" weighted_avg="466.56" change_in_wtd_avg="-1.73"/><record item_desc="S.P.B. - Combo" number_trades="12" total_pounds="108,064" weighted_avg="431.54" change_in_wtd_avg="-.06"/><record item_desc="S.P.B. - Boxed" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/></report><report label="B/B and C/C"><record item_desc="Chuck, chuck tender (116B)" number_trades="30" total_pounds="73,521" weighted_avg="311.27" change_in_wtd_avg="-2.08"/><record item_desc="Round, knuckle, peeled (167A)" number_trades="39" total_pounds="199,293" weighted_avg="323.60" change_in_wtd_avg=".28"/><record item_desc="Loin, tenderloin, 2-3 lbs. (190)" number_trades="6" total_pounds="8,983" weighted_avg="447.16" change_in_wtd_avg="-12.52"/><record item_desc="Loin, tenderloin, 3-4 lbs. (190)" number_trades="43" total_pounds="69,979" weighted_avg="663.86" change_in_wtd_avg=".20"/><record item_desc="Loin, tenderloin, 4-5 lbs. (190)" number_trades="169" total_pounds="212,729" weighted_avg="773.68" change_in_wtd_avg="-4.71"/><record item_desc="Loin, tenderloin, 5-up lbs. (190)" number_trades="37" total_pounds="43,056" weighted_avg="617.55" change_in_wtd_avg="13.85"/><record item_desc="Flank, flank steak (193)" number_trades="82" total_pounds="116,533" weighted_avg="390.93" change_in_wtd_avg="1.18"/><record item_desc="Flank, rough ()" number_trades="44" total_pounds="54,606" weighted_avg="322.56" change_in_wtd_avg="-5.70"/></report><report label="FROZEN BONER/BREAKER"><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll, 6-8 lbs. (112)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll, 8-10 lbs. (112)" number_trades="6" total_pounds="16,005" weighted_avg="473.41" change_in_wtd_avg=".00"/><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll, 10-up lbs. (112)" number_trades="null" total_pounds="null" weighted_avg="null" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll-lip-on, 8-dn lbs. (112A)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll-lip-on, 8-up lbs. (112A)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Round, top inside c-off, 8-10 lbs. (169A)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Round, top inside c-off, 10-14 lbs. (169A)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Round, top inside c-off, 14-up lbs. (169A)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Loin, strip, bnls, 7-9 lbs. (180)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Loin, strip, bnls, 9-up lbs. (180)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/></report><report label="FROZEN CUTTER/CANNER"><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll, 4-6 lbs. (112)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll, 6-8 lbs. (112)" number_trades="5" total_pounds="85,800" weighted_avg="397.65" change_in_wtd_avg="-2.26"/><record item_desc="Rib, ribeye roll, 8-up lbs. (112)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/></report><report label="FROZEN B/B and C/C"><record item_desc="Loin, tenderloin, 2-3 lbs. (190)" number_trades="null" total_pounds="null" weighted_avg="null" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Loin, tenderloin, 3-4 lbs. (190)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Loin, tenderloin, 4-5 lbs. (190)" number_trades="null" total_pounds="null" weighted_avg="null" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Loin, tenderloin, 5-up lbs. (190)" number_trades="0" total_pounds="0" weighted_avg=".00" change_in_wtd_avg="null"/><record item_desc="Flank, flank steak (193)" number_trades="10" total_pounds="77,922" weighted_avg="332.06" change_in_wtd_avg="-.32"/></report></record></report></results>'

def version1(content):
    print('--- version1 ---')
    
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

    #r1 = requests.get(xml link)
    #root1 = ET.fromstring(r1.content)

    root1 = ET.fromstring(content)

    for item in root1.findall(".//report[@label='CUTTER/CANNER']"):
        for child in item:
            print(child.attrib.get('weighted_avg'), child.attrib.get('change_in_wtd_avg'))

    for item in root1.findall(".//report[@label='FROZEN CUTTER/CANNER']"):
        for child in item:
            print(child.attrib.get('weighted_avg'), child.attrib.get('change_in_wtd_avg'))


def version2(content):
    print('--- version2 ---')

    import lxml.etree as ET

    #r1 = requests.get(xml link)
    #root1 = ET.fromstring(r1.content)

    root1 = ET.fromstring(content)

    for item in root1.xpath(".//report[contains(@label, 'CUTTER/CANNER')]"):
        for child in item:
            print(child.attrib.get('weighted_avg'), child.attrib.get('change_in_wtd_avg'))


def version3(content):
    print('--- version3 ---')

    import lxml.etree as ET

    #r1 = requests.get(xml link)
    #root1 = ET.fromstring(r1.content)

    root1 = ET.fromstring(content)

    for item in root1.xpath(".//report[@label='CUTTER/CANNER' or @label='FROZEN CUTTER/CANNER']"):
        for child in item:
            print(child.attrib.get('weighted_avg'), child.attrib.get('change_in_wtd_avg'))

# --- main ---

version1(content)
version2(content)
version3(content)
```